# ubuntu software center unable to install packages?

Tags: software-center

There seems to be a programming error in aptdaemon, the software that allows you to install/remove software and to perform other package management related tasks.

```bash
Please report this error at http://launchpad.net/aptdaemon/+filebug and retry.
```

What do I have to do to fix it?

Comment: What were you doing when the error appeared? Do you have the last updates? Are you using 12.10, 12.04 or which version? Please, we need more information!

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem in the past and I have seen positive results from the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and then the command below which I have read was all that was needed for some people.

```
sudo apt-get install
```

**References:**

[Ubuntu Forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1612458&page=3)

[Bug Report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/aptdaemon/+bug/695799)

Comment: after doing that                                         bapi@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get clean
bapi@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package ttf-mscorefonts-installer needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.                                  now what?

Comment: Didi you try sudo apt-get install ? what was the response?